# Как описать функцию в конце файла, чтобы интерпретатор не ругался?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Описываю эту тестовую функцию в конце файла:

```
def test():
    print('Test')
```

Интерпретатор ругается, что функция неопределена так как он еще с ней не сталкивался

```
NameError: name 'test' is not defined
```

Можно ли как-то указать интерпретатору на нужную функцию?

Comment: а почему вы описываю эту тестовую функцию в конце файла , а скажем не в начале ?

Comment: @S. Nick, дело привычки и вкуса. Еще с C++ привык описывать функции в конце после main

Comment: попробуйте изменить своим вкусам и разместить функцию до ее вызова, например в самом начале.

Comment: Ну добавьте еще функцию main, а из нее вызывайте test: https://ideone.com/QXzLjv Технически test будет не в самом низу (ниже него будет вызов функции main), но ниже main.

Comment: @insolor, да, Ваш вариант решения мне нравится. Гениально и просто :)
Дайте ответ ниже, чтобы я мог его принять

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если очень хочется, можно добавить функцию `main`, а из нее уже вызывать функцию `test`:

```
def main():
    test()

def test():
    print('Test')

main()
```